# Pandas dataframe - cumulative frequency addition from other frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Entry    Frequency
A        20
B        10
C        15
```

I want to create a third dataframe which is a cumulative frequency that is
the summation of frequency counts of respective previous frequency column entries

```
Entry    Frequency   Cumulative Frequency
A        20            20
B        10            30
C        15            65
```

Any clue how to achieve this?

Comment: `df.Frequency.cumsum()`?

Comment: `df['Cumulative Frequency'] = df['Frequency'].cumsum()`

Comment: Did you mean 65 or 45?